# Detached NSThread memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsdata, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

With instruments i got a memory leak in this method of a detached thread :

```
-(void)goToThisUrl:(id) targetUrl
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    if (someCondition) {
        // Doing some stuff here
    }
    // Instruments show memory leak on data
    else {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: targetUrl]];
        myTargetImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        // When releasing data(because data retainCount = 2), i got:
        // Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
        //[data release];
    }   
    [pool release];
}
```

I don't understand this leak.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Kneejerk possibilities, given that there's no memory ownership problem in that code:

- if someone, somewhere else retains but doesn't correctly release myTargetImage then it's possible data will leak, and Instruments will show you the location indicated because it reports *where the object was created, not where it leaked*
- "For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread." ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW2)); unless you have specific authority that UIImage +imageWithData is safe (and I can't find any, but Apple have made this sort of detail very hard to find) then what you're doing is technically illegal and a functionality oddity like a leak shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: `what you're doing is technically illegal`: WHY? this image is not retained else where. Thanks.

Comment: It's a detached thread. It isn't the main thread. So if you don't have that specific authority then you are explicitly ignoring Apple's instruction that "UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread". In that case, all bets are off.

Comment: Ok, what about this leak? and how can i deal with that?

Comment: As per my answer: the leak is likely to be elsewhere than in that section of code, or a result of your unsafe threading strategy. You seem to be assuming the latter is an unrelated issue; there are no grounds to support that.

Comment: What Tommy said;  fix your threading problem first, then fix your memory leak, if any.

Comment: I don't have any threading problem, my code works really fine, just have some memory leak, if someone have an idea on why this happen, i'm glad to listen to his advices! Thanks.

Comment: @vince: according to the documentation your threading is not valid. You are relying on undocumented behaviour. Arguing that "it's obviously okay to ignore the documentation, because my code works fine, except that — you know — it doesn't" is untenable. The problem may not be the threading but you can't definitely say that it isn't, even ignoring the manifold other consequences of taking it on yourself to second-guess Apple's implementation and ignore their direct instructions.